# How to remove number in any url address in specific folder .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to remove numbers on the end url in specified folder, using htaccess.
(Numbers and minus sign befor numbers). For all urls in this folder.
**For example**

```
http://www.example.com/music/new-track-released-52
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/music/helo-there-4
```

**Need to look like**

```
http://www.example.com/music/new-track-released
http://www.example.com/music/helo-there
```

For all links in folder music
(I'm already removed php extension with htaccess)

How to do that?

Comment: Well, there are about 64826493 solutions for similar things alone here on SO. They all won't help you get started? Or didn't you look at them at all?

Comment: Sorry, I will check.

Comment: Do you already have some rules in your .htaccess, if yes then show them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/music/(.+)-[0-9]+$ /music/$1
```

Note that this is the version for the host configuration. For `.htaccess` style files this has to be slightly modified. Whenever possible you should prefer *not* to use `.htaccess` style files but the real host configuration instead. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and really slow the server down.